# Mathematica - Dynamic - ListPlot - baseline

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am performing baseline fitting to a raw dataset on a two-state equilibrium process.  The process involves fitting the sigmoidal curve to an upper and lower linear baseline, and subtracting so that you get a curve going from y=(0) (state 1) to y=(1) (state 2) over your x-value range instead y=(experimental observable values).

I'd like to expedite the baseline selection process through an interactive dynamic approach rather than manually typing in lhs/rhs x-values for each curve.  However, I'm noticing that the dynamic values behind the dynamic plots need to be on the screen for the plot to update.  Meaning, if I'm dynamic listplotting 4 points, and only three of these dynamic values (the output) are on screen then only three show up.  I have to scroll up or down through the notebook to "update" various values and then the plots correct themselves.

I have many calculations downstream after baseline selection, and I'd like to have all these subsequent calculations print up in a neat little grid near the sliders, without have to scroll.

I'm new to Dynamic, and also having trouble combining multiple plots (similar to Show) when held under the Dynamic functions.  I'd like to dynamically in one graphic plot the ListPlot of my rawData, the four baseline points, and then the fitted linear function through the selected rawData in the baseline area.  Next to this, I'll plot the two-state equilibrium plot (y=0 to 1) and then a single point representing the transition point of 50/50 state1/state2 (y=0.5).  All of these downstream processes are highly dependent on baseline selection, so I'd like to have the slider there and final plots to immediately see the results of various choices for baselines.

In summary, two questions:
1) screen refresh needed of output from dynamic values for updating dynamic plots not in the same input section
2) multiple plot types within a single graphic, dynamically

Best regards,
Kurtis

```
ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[
   1] = {{5.2, 171.5576923076923}, {5.4, 171.4583916083916}, {5.6, 
    171.36804195804197}, {5.8, 171.31552447552448}, {6, 
    171.31125874125877}, {6.2, 171.35321678321677}, {6.4, 
    171.41783216783216}, {6.6, 171.5072027972028}, {6.8, 
    171.61223776223778}, {7, 171.74020979020978}, {7.2, 
    171.8802097902098}, {7.4, 172.01412587412588}, {7.6, 
    172.1367832167832}, {7.8, 172.25818181818184}, {8, 
    172.37916083916082}, {8.2, 172.52223776223775}, {8.4, 
    172.65797202797202}, {8.6, 172.81475524475525}, {8.8, 
    172.97706293706293}, {9, 173.16314685314686}, {9.2, 
    173.35531468531468}, {9.4, 173.56958041958043}, {9.6, 
    173.7951048951049}, {9.8, 174.03153846153847}, {10, 
    174.2748951048951}, {10.2, 174.51762237762236}, {10.4, 
    174.7634265734266}, {10.6, 174.9851048951049}, {10.8, 
    175.1865034965035}, {11, 175.3864335664336}, {11.2, 
    175.59503496503498}, {11.4, 175.81916083916082}, {11.6, 
    176.02797202797203}, {11.8, 176.2442657342657}, {12, 
    176.45391608391608}, {12.2, 176.6886013986014}, {12.4, 
    176.9281118881119}, {12.6, 177.19}, {12.8, 177.47}, {13, 
    177.7390909090909}, {13.2, 178.01503496503494}, {13.4, 
    178.2923076923077}, {13.6, 178.60461538461539}, {13.8, 
    178.92685314685315}, {14, 179.24713286713288}, {14.2, 
    179.5781818181818}, {14.4, 179.93076923076922}, {14.6, 
    180.32083916083917}, {14.8, 180.71741258741258}, {15, 
    181.124965034965}, {15.2, 181.55125874125875}, {15.4, 
    181.97825174825175}, {15.6, 182.41020979020982}, {15.8, 
    182.8441258741259}, {16, 183.3011188811189}, {16.2, 
    183.77636363636367}, {16.4, 184.26951048951048}, {16.6, 
    184.80447552447555}, {16.8, 185.37951048951047}, {17, 
    185.97846153846154}, {17.2, 186.58356643356643}, {17.4, 
    187.19545454545454}, {17.6, 187.81587412587407}, {17.8, 
    188.44538461538463}, {18, 189.08426573426573}, {18.2, 
    189.73111888111887}, {18.4, 190.38111888111888}, {18.6, 
    191.04258741258744}, {18.8, 191.7199300699301}, {19, 
    192.43076923076922}, {19.2, 193.16111888111888}, {19.4, 
    193.91048951048953}, {19.6, 194.68713286713282}, {19.8, 
    195.4913286713287}, {20, 196.32006993006993}, {20.2, 
    197.17510489510488}, {20.4, 198.05881118881118}, {20.6, 
    198.95755244755247}, {20.8, 199.8584615384615}, {21, 
    200.76384615384615}, {21.2, 201.68461538461537}, {21.4, 
    202.62685314685316}, {21.6, 203.66496503496504}, {21.8, 
    204.81300699300698}, {22, 205.96062937062936}, {22.2, 
    206.8897902097902}, {22.4, 207.50202797202797}, {22.6, 
    207.81699300699304}, {22.8, 207.95888111888112}, {23, 
    208.02839160839162}, {23.2, 208.14692307692306}, {23.4, 
    208.4265734265734}, {23.6, 208.94608391608392}, {23.8, 
    209.81937062937064}, {24, 211.1255244755245}, {24.2, 
    212.82013986013985}, {24.4, 214.7145454545455}, {24.6, 
    216.61958041958042}, {24.8, 218.50860139860137}, {25, 
    220.42069930069928}, {25.2, 222.4111888111888}, {25.4, 
    224.48314685314682}, {25.6, 226.616013986014}, {25.8, 
    228.8025874125874}, {26, 231.0102097902098}, {26.2, 
    233.26111888111888}, {26.4, 235.54636363636362}, {26.6, 
    237.8906293706294}, {26.8, 240.30881118881118}, {27, 
    242.80363636363634}, {27.2, 245.37720279720278}, {27.4, 
    248.0467132867133}, {27.6, 250.82118881118885}, {27.8, 
    253.69622377622377}, {28, 256.65937062937064}, {28.2, 
    259.7168531468531}, {28.4, 262.8809090909091}, {28.6, 
    266.136083916084}, {28.8, 269.48853146853145}, {29, 
    272.9494405594406}, {29.2, 276.5634265734266}, {29.4, 
    280.31496503496504}, {29.6, 284.1983916083916}, {29.8, 
    288.2063636363637}, {30, 292.3523076923077}, {30.2, 
    296.6392307692308}, {30.4, 301.0708391608391}, {30.6, 
    305.62391608391613}, {30.8, 310.3113286713287}, {31, 
    315.11034965034963}, {31.2, 320.04965034965034}, {31.4, 
    325.1569230769231}, {31.6, 330.4420979020979}, {31.8, 
    335.90902097902097}, {32, 341.55034965034963}, {32.2, 
    347.37482517482516}, {32.4, 353.38538461538457}, {32.6, 
    359.5694405594406}, {32.8, 365.93888111888117}, {33, 
    372.4761538461538}, {33.2, 379.2182517482518}, {33.4, 
    386.1609790209791}, {33.6, 393.32629370629365}, {33.8, 
    400.7041958041958}, {34, 408.26265734265735}, {34.2, 
    416.02657342657346}, {34.4, 423.96489510489516}, {34.6, 
    432.1181818181819}, {34.8, 440.4820979020979}, {35, 
    448.6806293706294}, {35.2, 456.86342657342664}, {35.4, 
    465.53755244755246}, {35.6, 475.66034965034964}, {35.8, 
    487.5865734265734}, {36, 501.1653146853147}, {36.2, 
    516.0813286713288}, {36.4, 531.9086013986014}, {36.6, 
    548.2587412587412}, {36.8, 564.6713986013987}, {37, 
    580.6118881118881}, {37.2, 595.7270629370629}, {37.4, 
    609.4006293706293}, {37.6, 622.2286013986014}, {37.8, 
    634.5355944055943}, {38, 647.2777622377623}, {38.2, 
    660.156153846154}, {38.4, 673.3221678321679}, {38.6, 
    686.4862237762237}, {38.8, 699.9664335664336}, {39, 
    713.5155244755244}, {39.2, 727.4389510489511}, {39.4, 
    741.0336363636363}, {39.6, 755.0702097902098}, {39.8, 
    769.5217482517482}, {40, 785.5246153846156}, {40.2, 
    802.3835664335664}, {40.4, 820.4558741258742}, {40.6, 
    838.8953146853147}, {40.8, 858.1897202797202}, {41, 
    877.5658741258741}, {41.2, 897.573986013986}, {41.4, 
    917.3868531468532}, {41.6, 937.4052447552448}, {41.8, 
    956.7482517482517}, {42, 976.6904895104893}, {42.2, 
    997.0346153846153}, {42.4, 1018.8477622377623}, {42.6, 
    1041.1142657342657}, {42.8, 1064.3213286713287}, {43, 
    1088.1560139860142}, {43.2, 1112.473986013986}, {43.4, 
    1137.4900699300697}, {43.6, 1164.0341958041959}, {43.8, 
    1192.6026573426573}, {44, 1223.4609090909091}, {44.2, 
    1255.9941258741258}, {44.4, 1290.8709790209791}, {44.6, 
    1327.0130769230768}, {44.8, 1364.6239860139858}, {45, 
    1402.7880419580417}, {45.2, 1442.381118881119}, {45.4, 
    1482.7290909090907}, {45.6, 1523.66013986014}, {45.8, 
    1565.570979020979}, {46, 1609.5718881118883}, {46.2, 
    1656.1732867132866}, {46.4, 1705.5791608391607}, {46.6, 
    1757.082797202797}, {46.8, 1811.405664335664}, {47, 
    1867.7601398601398}, {47.2, 1927.0214685314686}, {47.4, 
    1988.903566433566}, {47.6, 2053.9727272727273}, {47.8, 
    2121.3558741258735}, {48, 2191.253076923077}, {48.2, 
    2263.4567132867137}, {48.4, 2338.992097902097}, {48.6, 
    2417.6206293706296}, {48.8, 2499.507062937063}, {49, 
    2584.0679020979014}, {49.2, 2672.40048951049}, {49.4, 
    2764.2509090909093}, {49.6, 2860.08972027972}, {49.8, 
    2958.8880419580414}, {50, 3061.5296503496506}, {50.2, 
    3167.954475524476}, {50.4, 3279.3267132867136}, {50.6, 
    3394.996363636363}, {50.8, 3514.5386013986017}, {51, 
    3637.8941958041955}, {51.2, 3767.8172727272727}, {51.4, 
    3907.369160839161}, {51.6, 4057.940839160839}, {51.8, 
    4218.387692307691}, {52, 4387.486363636363}, {52.2, 
    4559.219090909091}, {52.4, 4737.994405594407}, {52.6, 
    4926.850629370629}, {52.8, 5133.069790209789}, {53, 
    5351.979300699301}, {53.2, 5580.233216783217}, {53.4, 
    5815.771258741259}, {53.6, 6059.474335664335}, {53.8, 
    6310.2300699300695}, {54, 6566.168951048951}, {54.2, 
    6824.079510489511}, {54.4, 7080.809090909091}, {54.6, 
    7333.146293706293}, {54.8, 7587.8459440559445}, {55, 
    7850.626853146852}, {55.2, 8125.57027972028}, {55.4, 
    8409.073496503495}, {55.6, 8698.83132867133}, {55.8, 
    8996.236433566435}, {56, 9300.716293706295}, {56.2, 
    9614.424195804197}, {56.4, 9936.465874125875}, {56.6, 
    10267.16895104895}, {56.8, 10604.112797202795}, {57, 
    10948.749580419582}, {57.2, 11300.41020979021}, {57.4, 
    11659.683006993006}, {57.6, 12023.626783216785}, {57.8, 
    12392.80202797203}, {58, 12766.768741258744}, {58.2, 
    13147.152517482516}, {58.4, 13533.405594405594}, {58.6, 
    13929.522447552448}, {58.8, 14331.496503496504}, {59, 
    14735.11027972028}, {59.2, 15134.907552447552}, {59.4, 
    15531.639090909091}, {59.6, 15926.898251748251}, {59.8, 
    16319.009370629366}, {60, 16708.945804195802}, {60.2, 
    17100.06636363636}, {60.4, 17496.746923076924}, {60.6, 
    17899.96601398601}, {60.8, 18310.962377622378}, {61, 
    18733.114335664337}, {61.2, 19158.742027972025}, {61.4, 
    19578.491538461538}, {61.6, 19983.563636363637}, {61.8, 
    20383.41286713287}, {62, 20771.78615384616}, {62.2, 
    21143.815874125874}, {62.4, 21493.19979020979}, {62.6, 
    21831.533146853144}, {62.8, 22165.208671328666}, {63, 
    22497.004265734264}, {63.2, 22829.18895104895}, {63.4, 
    23165.61839160839}, {63.6, 23505.106223776227}, {63.8, 
    23845.65895104895}, {64, 24185.918321678324}, {64.2, 
    24530.909580419582}, {64.4, 24870.472797202798}, {64.6, 
    25198.522797202797}, {64.8, 25507.47804195804}, {65, 
    25802.223846153847}, {65.2, 26082.483426573428}, {65.4, 
    26348.033426573424}, {65.6, 26600.166853146857}, {65.8, 
    26840.285384615385}, {66, 27072.183286713287}, {66.2, 
    27294.89937062937}, {66.4, 27510.708951048953}, {66.6, 
    27720.160139860138}, {66.8, 27922.566853146855}, {67, 
    28118.26083916084}, {67.2, 28307.706083916084}, {67.4, 
    28494.77258741259}, {67.6, 28679.58657342657}, {67.8, 
    28860.11972027972}, {68, 29039.42153846154}, {68.2, 
    29210.7306993007}, {68.4, 29366.41545454545}, {68.6, 
    29502.546223776226}, {68.8, 29629.67433566434}, {69, 
    29744.836363636365}, {69.2, 29836.08020979021}, {69.4, 
    29898.33790209791}, {69.6, 29933.56769230769}, {69.8, 
    29959.04762237762}, {70, 29975.020909090912}, {70.2, 
    29991.388531468532}, {70.4, 30006.784055944052}, {70.6, 
    30018.964685314684}, {70.8, 30026.687132867133}, {71, 
    30047.393426573428}, {71.2, 30084.82174825175}, {71.4, 
    30135.9965034965}, {71.6, 30182.328111888113}, {71.8, 
    30225.142167832168}, {72, 30268.663566433566}, {72.2, 
    30319.640629370628}, {72.4, 30372.744545454545}, {72.6, 
    30427.39160839161}, {72.8, 30477.89188811188}, {73, 
    30521.84727272727}, {73.2, 30553.777762237765}, {73.4, 
    30573.294825174824}, {73.6, 30571.749790209793}, {73.8, 
    30562.458741258743}, {74, 30552.884825174824}, {74.2, 
    30553.355174825174}, {74.4, 30564.295454545452}, {74.6, 
    30576.382587412594}, {74.8, 30594.90377622378}, {75, 
    30610.827692307692}, {75.2, 30633.06699300699}, {75.4, 
    30653.350000000002}, {75.6, 30666.33594405594}, {75.8, 
    30668.923426573427}, {76, 30668.75461538462}, {76.2, 
    30670.575314685306}, {76.4, 30670.93328671329}, {76.6, 
    30667.266083916085}, {76.8, 30663.819300699302}, {77, 
    30647.977062937065}, {77.2, 30618.72202797203}, {77.4, 
    30565.47013986014}, {77.6, 30508.620349650355}, {77.8, 
    30455.27230769231}, {78, 30410.724055944054}, {78.2, 
    30383.247272727276}, {78.4, 30363.072377622375}, {78.6, 
    30355.305034965033}, {78.8, 30342.20923076923}, {79, 
    30340.65146853147}, {79.2, 30337.188811188807}, {79.4, 
    30331.158181818184}, {79.6, 30315.162097902103}, {79.8, 
    30295.13181818182}, {80, 30271.48195804196}, {80.2, 
    30250.13118881119}, {80.4, 30224.207062937065}, {80.6, 
    30201.98300699301}, {80.8, 30170.62013986014}, {81, 
    30157.62923076923}, {81.2, 30143.96188811189}, {81.4, 
    30141.00909090909}, {81.6, 30117.328741258738}, {81.8, 
    30092.859790209794}, {82, 30056.212097902095}, {82.2, 
    30011.19230769231}, {82.4, 29951.637552447555}, {82.6, 
    29881.86965034965}, {82.8, 29809.408811188812}, {83, 
    29743.92013986014}, {83.2, 29687.225244755246}, {83.4, 
    29650.274545454547}, {83.6, 29609.51027972028}, {83.8, 
    29570.36111888112}, {84, 29528.284685314688}, {84.2, 
    29495.74104895105}, {84.4, 29464.83104895105}, {84.6, 
    29432.034545454546}, {84.8, 29397.90867132867}, {85, 
    29359.92979020979}, {85.2, 29328.5486013986}, {85.4, 
    29309.78937062937}, {85.6, 29295.625034965036}, {85.8, 
    29279.513916083917}, {86, 29255.218671328672}, {86.2, 
    29234.38566433567}, {86.4, 29227.73384615385}, {86.6, 
    29216.327202797198}, {86.8, 29201.22685314685}, {87, 
    29162.052937062937}, {87.2, 29113.863776223774}, {87.4, 
    29051.34391608391}, {87.6, 28988.94237762238}, {87.8, 
    28926.36160839161}, {88, 28856.33132867133}, {88.2, 
    28782.890699300704}, {88.4, 28712.760769230772}, {88.6, 
    28660.5920979021}, {88.8, 28620.868461538463}, {89, 
    28583.4386013986}, {89.2, 28546.60818181818}, {89.4, 
    28502.005384615386}, {89.6, 28462.87916083916}, {89.8, 
    28422.843076923076}, {90, 28389.142517482516}, {90.2, 
    28339.938461538462}, {90.4, 28275.94958041958}, {90.6, 
    28203.151538461538}, {90.8, 28132.62300699301}, {91, 
    28069.04839160839}, {91.2, 27992.026083916087}, {91.4, 
    27914.222797202798}, {91.6, 27834.239160839163}, {91.8, 
    27766.07118881119}, {92, 27716.52062937063}, {92.2, 
    27679.7613986014}, {92.4, 27652.8013986014}, {92.6, 
    27618.464055944052}, {92.8, 27588.78923076923}, {93, 
    27574.388531468536}, {93.2, 27566.27888111888}, {93.4, 
    27547.25811188811}, {93.6, 27502.117692307693}, {93.8, 
    27444.676573426572}};

ramp1FSmoothFunc[1] = Interpolation[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1]]


ClearAll[helixMidPoint, helixLineLength, helixLowPoint, \
helixLowPointRFU, helixHighPoint, helixHighPointRFU]
ClearAll[coilMidPoint, coilLineLength, coilLowPoint, coilLowPointRFU, \
coilHighPoint, coilHighPointRFU]
ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1];
helixLowBarrier = 10;
helixHighBarrier = 40;
coilLowBarrier = 60;
coilHighBarrier = 90;

{Slider[Dynamic[helixMidPoint], {helixLowBarrier, helixHighBarrier}], 
 Dynamic[helixMidPoint], 
 Dynamic[helixMidPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixMidPoint]], 
 Slider[Dynamic[helixLineLength], {5, 25}], Dynamic[helixLineLength]}

{Slider[Dynamic[coilMidPoint], {coilLowBarrier, coilHighBarrier}], 
 Dynamic[coilMidPoint], 
 Dynamic[coilMidPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilMidPoint]], 
 Slider[Dynamic[coilLineLength], {5, 25}], Dynamic[coilLineLength]}

Dynamic[{ListPlot[{ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[
     1], {{helixLowPoint, helixLowPointRFU}}, {{helixHighPoint, 
      helixHighPointRFU}}, {{coilLowPoint, 
      coilLowPointRFU}}, {{coilHighPoint, coilHighPointRFU}}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Small], PointSize[Large], PointSize[Large],
      PointSize[Large], PointSize[Large]}],

  Grid[{{, "temperature (C)", "Interpolated RFU"}, {"helix low point",
      Dynamic[helixLowPoint = helixMidPoint - helixLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[helixLowPointRFU = 
       ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][helixLowPoint]]}, {"helix high point", 
     Dynamic[helixHighPoint = helixMidPoint + helixLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[helixHighPointRFU = 
       ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][
        helixHighPoint]]}, {, ,}, {"coil low point", 
     Dynamic[coilLowPoint = coilMidPoint - coilLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[coilLowPointRFU = 
       ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilLowPoint]]}, {"coil high point", 
     Dynamic[coilHighPoint = coilMidPoint + coilLineLength/2], 
     Dynamic[coilHighPointRFU = ramp1FSmoothFunc[1][coilHighPoint]]}},
    Frame -> All]}]

Dynamic[ramp1FBaseLinesTEST = 
  Plot[{ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST[temp], 
    ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST[temp]}, {temp, 1, 100}]]




Dynamic[ramp1FHelixTEST = 
  Select[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], 
   helixLowPoint <= #[[1]] <= helixHighPoint &]]

Dynamic[ramp1FHCoilTEST = 
  Select[ramp1FCelsiusXRFUSmooth[1], 
   coilLowPoint <= #[[1]] <= coilHighPoint &]]

Dynamic[ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST = 
  Fit[ramp1FHelixTEST, {1, temp}, temp]]
Dynamic[ramp1FHelixLinFitEqTEST[temp_] = ramp1FHelixLinFitTEST]
Dynamic[ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST = Fit[ramp1FHCoilTEST, {1, temp}, temp]]
Dynamic[ramp1FCoilLinFitEqTEST[temp_] = ramp1FCoilLinFitTEST]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate&lang=en), it should automate what you're trying to do with Dynamic. For example, `Manipulate[Show[<plots>], {param, min, max}]` should work.